# To discontinue line in many lines in Xcode

Tags: xcode, development

I have the following code, but I do not want it to continue to many lines. I want everything in one line.

How can you prevent this from happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Choose a file.
2. `View` -> `Utilities` -> `Show File inspector` then deselect Wrap lines in "Text Settings".